# Why $T_{\infty}\sin(x^2)$ could be written as $x^2+o(x^4)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation, taylor-expansion

I am confused about the little-oh notation in the Taylor series.

As we know, $T_{\infty}\sin(x)=x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\cdots$

By substitution, I got $T_{\infty}\sin(x^2)=x^2 - \frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^{10}}{5!}+\cdots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}+\cdots$

I think I can also write the series as $\sin(x^2) = x^2 + o(x^2)$, but I don't know why $\sin(x^2) = x^2 + o(x^4)$ is equivalent too?

Comment: The two statements are both true, but they are not equivalent: Functions that are $o(x^4)$ are also $o(x^2)$ but the reverse is not true (consider $x \mapsto x^3$, for example).

Comment: @Travis Thank you, so I wonder whether I can cut any Taylor series by replacing the right terms as $o(x^n)$, where $n$ is the highest degree in the left part? i.e. $\sin(x^2) = x^2 - \frac{x^6}{3!}+o(x^6)$

Comment: Yes, this is a general feature of Taylor series. Note that in the case of $\sin(x^2)$ we can actually do a little better, as the several terms after the leading one are zero, so that $T_{\infty} \sin (x^2) = x^2 + o(x^5)$.

Comment: @Travis Oh I see! I guess in this case, $T_{\infty} \sin (x^2) = x^2 + o(x^6)$ is not valid, right?

Comment: Correct, as there is a nonzero term $c x^6$ in the series.

Comment: One comparison might be that the number 0.010001 is 0.01 to 2 decimal places, *and also* to 4 decimal places, though not to 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

"I think I can also write the series as $sin(x)=x^2 +o(x^2)$"
  Yes, as long as x is less than 1, higher powers than 2 of x will be smaller than $x^2$ so will go to 0 faster as x goes to 0. "o(f(x)) means something that goes to zero [b]faster[/b] than f(x).

"but I don't know why $sin(x)=x^2 +o(x^4)$" 
It **isn't**.  I think what you mean is $sin(x)= x^2+ O(x^4)$.  The 'large O' means "goes to 0 at least as fast" while the 'little o' means "goes to 0 faster".

Comment: I am so sorry that I have edited the question. I am confused about whether I could write it as $\sin(x^2) = x^2 + o(x^4)$?

Comment: @user247327 - are you sure that $\sin (x^2)-x^2$ isn't $o(x^4)$?